# How to determine the sum of a series that is neither geometric nor arithmetic but quadratic or cubic?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to determine the formula of the sum of a series given its $n$th-term formula like:
$$U_n= n^2+n$$

or

$$U_n= 6n^2 -12n + 5$$

Comment: Avoid asking problem statement questions. You can do this by including more information, such as where you got this problem and what you have tried, even if you don't think it will lead anywhere. Such information helps us help you, so you will be expected to bring something to the table when posting questions. For more information, see [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959).

Answer (score 2):

It is known that 
$\sum_{k=1}^nk=1+2+3+...+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, and
$\sum_{k=1}^n{k^2}=1^2+2^2+3^2+...+n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$

By using these fact, we can evaluate the sum you are talking about.

Let $U_n=n^2+n$

$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^nU_k=\sum_{k=1}^n{k^2+k}=\sum_{k=1}^nk^2+\sum_{k=1}^nk$

$S_n=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Simplify and we get

$S_n=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3}$

Furthermore, if you want to calculate the sum of cube of first $n$ natural number,

$1^3+2^3+3^3+...+n^3=(1+2+3+...+n)^2=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$

The main idea is to separate each term based on their power $(2,2^2,$ or $2^3)$ and calculate each sum with the formula.

For $U_n=\frac1{n^2+n}=\frac{n+1-n}{n(n+1)}=\frac{n+1}{n(n+1)}-\frac{n}{n(n+1)}=\frac1{n}-\frac1{n+1}$

$S_n=U_1+U_2+U_3+...+U_n=(\frac11-\frac12)+(\frac12-\frac13)+(\frac13-\frac14)+...+(\frac1n+\frac1{n+1})$

$\frac12$ and $-\frac12$ will cancel each other out. The same thing happens for $\frac13,\frac14,\frac15,...,\frac1n$. Thus the remaining terms are $S_n=\frac11-\frac1{n+1}=\frac{(n+1)-1}{n+1}=\frac{n}{n+1}$

Comment: Thanks. But how if the terms are a denominator like in Un= 1/(n^2+n), how to separate each of them?

Comment: For Un=1/(n^2+n), I usually use factorizing and separating the term so that telescoping is able to be done. Un=1/n(n+1)=(1/n)-(1/(n+1)). By summing up their value, lots of term are going to cancel out and leave us with (usually) simple arithmetic.

Comment: I tried but stuck. Could you please do it?

Comment: Un=1/(n(n+1))=((n+1)-n)/(n(n+1)=(n+1)/(n(n+1))-n/(n(n+1))=(1/n)-(1/(n+1)). Then evaluate Sn. Sn=U1+U2+U3+...+Un=(1/1-1/2)+(1/2-1/3)+(1/3-1/4)+...+(1/n-1/(n+1)). Consider the fact that there are -1/2 and +1/2 that will cancel each other our. The same thing happens for 1/3, 1/4, 1/5, ..., 1/n. Thus the remaining terms are Sn=1/1-1/(n+1)=n/(n+1)

Comment: Thanks. I din't use that +n-n, that's why I was stuck. I usually use that technique in mathematical induction. Didn't realize that the technique is also useful in sequence and series topic

Answer (score 0):

First you need the forward difference operator on a function f
 $$ \Delta f(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$$.So if you are given a function g and you need to sum it from a t0 b, you find f such that $g(x)=\Delta f(x)$. Then
$$ \sum_{i=a}^b g(i)=\sum_{i=a}^b \Delta f(i)= f(b+1)-f(a) $$
Then you need falling factorials $n^{(i)}=n(n-1)...(n-i+1) $ , the relations
$ \Delta n^{(i)}=in^{(i-1)} $  and $ n^{(i)}=\Delta(((1/(i+1))n^{(i+1)}) $.Then you need to convert a polynomial to a polynomial in falling factorials. Use $ n^{(1)}=n^1=n$ and 
$ n^{(i)}n=n^{(i+1)}+in^{(i)}$ so $n^2=n^{(2)}+n^{(1)}$ and 
$$ n^3=n^2n=(n^{(2)}+n^{(1)})n=n^{(2)}n+n^{(1)}n =n^{(3)}+2n^{(2)}+n^{(2)}+n^{(1)}$$
$$ =n^{(3)}+3n^{(2)}+n^{(1)}$$ 
So $ \sum_{x=a}^b x^3 =\sum_{(x=a)}^b x^{(3)}+3x^{(2)}+x^{(1)}$
$$ =\sum_{x=a}^b \Delta ((1/4)x^{(4)}+x^{(3)}+(1/2)x^{(2)}) $$
$$=(1/4)(b+1)b(b-1)(b-2)+(b+1)b(b-1)+(1/2)(b+1)b$$
$$-((1/4)a(a-1)(a-2)(a-3)+a(a-1)(a-2)+(1/2)a(a-1)) $$